# Unable to dynamically update display report in Report Viewer Control

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc

I am using following code to change the reports displayed in the report viewer control on Button click event.

```
private void ReinitializeViewer(string tsReport)
        {
            ReportDataSource ReportDataSourceX = new ReportDataSource();
            this.PurchaseReprotViewer.Reset();
            this.PurchaseReprotViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = tsReport;
            if (tsReport.Contains("Rpt_PurchaseInvoice.rdlc"))
            {
                this.purchaseTableAdapter.Fill(this.gmsDataSet.purchase);
                ReportDataSourceX.Name = "PurchaseInvoiceDataSet";
                ReportDataSourceX.Value = this.gmsDataSet.Tables["purchase"];
            }
            else
            {
               ReportDataSourceX.Name = "DataSet1";

              // ReportDataSourceX.Value = Me.MyBindingSource1
            }

            this.PurchaseReprotViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportDataSourceX);
            //this.purchaseTableAdapter.Fill(this.gmsDataSet.purchase);
            this.PurchaseReprotViewer.RefreshReport();
        }

        private void Cmd_PurchaseInvoices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReinitializeViewer("Rpt_PurchaseInvoice.rdlc");
        }
```

But I am getting a strange error in the output.

[image]

I am unable to identify what's going wrong in the above code.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be related to the order in which events are fired when a aspx.NET web page is create & loaded,  button click events tend to take place fairly late in the cycle (at a guess) The Report Control could be complaining about the lack of a definition because that check has happened before the OnClick event has had a chance to set it up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by myself.

Following code worked for me:

```
private void ReinitializeViewer(string tsReport)
{
       ReportDataSource ReportDataSourceX = new ReportDataSource();
        this.PurchaseReprotViewer.Reset();

        if (tsReport.Contains("Rpt_PurchaseInvoice.rdlc"))
        {
            ReportDataSourceX.Name = "PurchaseInvoiceDataSet";
            ReportDataSourceX.Value = this.purchaseBindingSource;
            this.PurchaseReprotViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportDataSourceX);
            this.PurchaseReprotViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = tsReport;
            this.PurchaseReprotViewer.RefreshReport();
        }

    }
```